# Take value From listbox to label in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take value from query to label in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243118/take-value-from-query-to-label-in-c-sharp)

Im newbie in C#

I have 3 table in Ms SQL.. tbl_staff, tbl_logs and tbl_department

In Windows form, I have one list box and two label. List box will display userID in tbl_logs.

When the user chooses from the list box, the label will change a value and display the name and department in same form.

The problem is, how can i paste a value from list box to label based on query?

This is my SQL query

```
SELECT tbl_staff.userID, tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs.userID and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment;
```

How to do in c# and paste value to label? Below is my current code

```
SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(connString);

                openCon.Open();

                SqlCommand queryChangeName = new SqlCommand();

                int index = listStaff.SelectedIndex;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                ds.Clear();

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT tbl_staff.userID, tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff.SelectedValue + " and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment";", openCon);
```

I dont have any idea to do, hope someone can help me to resolve this problem. And sorry for bad english.

Thanks alot ;)

Comment: why you are write `WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff.SelectedValue + "` ?

Comment: To filter the record.
Any mistake? hope can show me... hehe.. thanks..;)

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to do an initial load of the dataset (including staff id, name, and department) at the start, into a local `DataTable`.

Then use this to populate your drop down.  You can then refer back to your local DataTable when you have a selected index from the listbox, to get the associated name and department.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing now is just filling up the database.Maybe you should have a look here [Start To Windows Form](http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/)  hope this helps