# Take value from query to label in C#

Tags: c#, sql

How can i take value from query result to label?

I have two label, one is **labelName** and one more is **labelDepartment**

So when i run the query, how can i get value from query result and assign it to label using c#?

This is my Sql Command:

```
  "SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department 
    FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department 
    WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff.SelectedValue + " and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment;"
```

This is current code in C#

```
//Open SQL connection

SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(connString);
openCon.Open();

string SQL = string.Format("SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs.userID and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment" + listStaff.SelectedValue + ";");


SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    labelName.Text = reader["tbl_staff.staffName"];
    labelDepartment.Text = reader["tbl_department.department"];
}
```

Note : Our record will return one row only.. 
MS SQL and C#.. thanks for help...;)

Comment: Maybe you can try to show in code what  you really want to achieve.

Comment: Have u managed to get the result from SQL query? Also please share your C# code.

Comment: Hello @Tomas, thanks for help.. For you information, I don`t know to much to write code in c#.. Can I use dataReader to solve this problem?

Hello @Arkain, thanks for your respons. Im still newbie in C#, can you explain me what function for ADO.Net, LINQ and ENTITY Framework?

Thanks for help...:)

Hello @ssilas777, ok i will share... Thanks again...;)

Comment: Is this the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241946/take-value-from-listbox-to-label-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli , Actually is same.. hehe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        string name = null;
        string department = null;
        string listStaff = "MylistStaff";

        string sql =  "SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department " +
            "FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department " +
            "WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff + " and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment;";
        //change this connection string... visit www.connectionstrings.com
        string connString = "Server=localhost; Database=myDatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=Yes";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    name = reader[0] as string;
                    department = reader[1] as string;
                    //break for single row or you can continue if you have multiple rows...
                    break;
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

department and listStaff can then easily be applied to label text like:

DepartmentLabel.Text = department;

Comment: superb answer Gregor, it helped me too

Answer (score 1):

you need to read the result via a SQLDataReader

```
SQLCommand command = new SQLCommand("your sql string here");
SQLDataReader reader = command.executeReader();
while(reader.read())
{
 set your label values here with reader["cloumn"]
}
```

Comment: Like this?  

labelName.Text=["tbl_staff.staffName"];

Comment: +1, I thought to write the exact code. But because I didn't know how many rows query has to return I haven't posted. Because if the are several rows, what row should be used to get column value. On the other hand you may use ExecuteScalar method if there will be one value.

Comment: @seeker. Query result just return one rows only.. hehe... Thanks for help my friend...:)

Comment: @chuki2 like this: `labelName.Text=reader["tbl_staff.staffName"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can read content of the row(s) that query returned using `DataReader` class. It has methods to get single value, or you can iterate for each row. Tell me how many rows youR query returns so I can provide the exact code.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one - Also set your connection string along with this code

```
SQLCommand command = new SQLCommand();
command.CommandText = " SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department 
    FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department 
    WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff.SelectedValue + " and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment ";

SQLDataReader reader = command.executeReader();

while(reader.read())
{
 labelName.Text = reader.GetString(0);
 labelDepartment.Text = reader.GetString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do:

```
private void getData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(" SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department 
FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department 
WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs." + listStaff.SelectedValue + " and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",user);
    sqlDa.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
           lable.Text = dt.Rows[0]["staffName"].ToString(); //Where "staffName" is ColumnName 

    }
        connection.Close();
}
```

Suggest to use a stored procedure not in line query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

[stored procedure example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/storedprocedure12052007003126AM/storedprocedure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Open SQL connection

SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(connString);
openCon.Open();

string SQL = string.Format("SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs.userID and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment" + listStaff.SelectedValue + ";");


SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    labelName.Text = reader["tbl_staff.staffName"].ToString();
    labelDepartment.Text = reader["tbl_department.department"].ToString();
}
```

Convert Type is what you left in your code....

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing only This

```
SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(connString);
openCon.Open();

string SQL = string.Format("SELECT tbl_staff.staffName,tbl_department.department FROM tbl_staff,tbl_logs,tbl_department WHERE tbl_staff.userID = tbl_logs.userID and tbl_staff.idDepartment = tbl_department.idDepartment" + listStaff.SelectedValue + ";");


SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    labelName.Text = reader["tbl_staff.staffName"].toString();
    labelDepartment.Text = reader["tbl_department.department"].toString();
}`
```

Answer (score -2):

Populate the Dataset with your Query and then retrieve values from Dataset and assign it to your label.

Lets say  your Dataset is DS then:

```
labelName.Text=DS.Tables[0]["tbl_staff.staffName"].tostring();
labelDepartment.Text=DS.Tables[0]["tbl_department.department"].tostring();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What are you using as Backend MSACCESS or SQL?

Comment: Sorry.. Im use MS SQL 2008..;)

By the way, i will try first. Anything I will ask you again..  Thanks for help Rohit...;)